# Limits defined for negative factorials (i.e. $(-n)!,\space n\in\mathbb{N}$)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, factorial, gamma-function

I apoligize if this is a stupid/obvious question, but last night I was wondering how we can compute limits for factorials of negative integers, for instance, how do we evaluate:

$$\lim_{x\to-3}\frac{x!}{(2x)!}=-120$$

Neither $x!$, nor $(2x)!$ are defined for $x\in\mathbb{Z}^{-}$, and indeed, both are singularities according to the graph of $\Gamma(x+1)$.

The book I am reading calculates this using a previously shown identity that:

$$F\left(\left.{1-c-2n,-2n \atop c}\right|-1\right)=(-1)^{n}\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\frac{(c-1)!}{(c+n-1)!},\space\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}$$

And then, the more general Kummer's Formula:

$$F\left(\left.{a,b \atop 1+b-a}\right|-1\right)=\frac{(b/2)!}{b!}(b-a)^{\underline{b/2}}$$

It then shows that they would only produce consistent results if:

$$(-1)^{n}\frac{(2n)!}{n!}=\lim_{b\to-2n}{\frac{(b/2)!}{b!}}=\lim_{x\to-n}{\frac{x!}{(2x)!}},\space n\in\mathbb{Z}^{*}$$

It then gives the example of $n=3$, proving that:

$$\lim_{x\to-3}{\frac{x!}{(2x)!}}=-\frac{6!}{3!}=-120$$

However, using Wolfram|Alpha, I can see that there are other such limits defined (such as $\lim_{x\to-3}{\frac{x!}{(8x)!}}=-103408066955539906560000$.

Without using the hypergeometric series, how could we evaluate limits such as these?

Again, sorry if this is a stupid question, thanks in advance!

Comment: (Some of your limits have $n\to$ but $x$ rather than $n$ in the expression.) The Gamma function has simple poles at negative integers with easily-describable residues (alternating sign reciprocals of factorials); this could probably be exploited.

Comment: @anon I've fixed the limits. So would it be legal to do something like: $$\lim_{x\to-3}{\frac{x!}{(4x)!}}=\frac{(-1)^{3}}{3!}\div\frac{(-1)^{12}}{12!}=-79833600$$ Which Wolfram|Alpha says is the correct answer?

Comment: @Shaktal: Would it be legal?  Not without additional explantion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to compute $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -n} \frac {\Pi(x)}{\Pi(mx)}$ when $x$ is near a negative integer.
$\Pi$ is the 'natural' extension of the factorial : $\Pi(n)=n!$ and $\Pi(z)=\Gamma(z+1)$ (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Pi_function))

In this form the ["Euler's reflection formula"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) becomes simply (for $\operatorname{sinc}(z)=\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z}$) :
$$\Pi(-z)\Pi(z)=\frac 1{\operatorname{sinc}(z)}$$

$$ \lim_{x\to -n}\ \frac {\Pi(x)}{\Pi(mx)}=\lim_{x\to -n}\frac {\Pi(-mx)\operatorname{sinc}(-mx)}{\Pi(-x)\operatorname{sinc}(-x)}$$
 $$ =\lim_{t\to n}\frac {\Pi(mt)\operatorname{sinc}(mt)}{\Pi(t)\operatorname{sinc}(t)}$$

It remains to prove that $\ \lim_{t\to n} \frac {\operatorname{sinc(mt)}}{\operatorname{sinc(t)}}=\frac {(-1)^{(m-1)n}}m$ (you may use l'Hôpital's rule for that) and to conclude!

Comment: Actually, $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to n} \frac {\operatorname{sinc(mt)}}{\operatorname{sinc(t)}}=\frac{(-1)^{(m-1)t}}{m}$

Comment: @GenericHuman: Oops you are right, thanks to notice!

Answer (score 4):

Using anon's "pole" idea, with **definition** $x! := \Gamma(x+1)$ we have:
$$\begin{align}
x! &= \Gamma(x+1) = \frac{1}{2}\;\frac{1}{x+3}+O(1)\qquad\text{as $x \to -3$},
\\
(2x)! &= \Gamma(2x+1) = -\frac{1}{240}\;\frac{1}{x+3} + O(1)\qquad\text{as $x \to -3$},
\\
\frac{x!}{(2x)!} &= \frac{1/2}{-1/240}+O(x+3)\qquad\text{as $x \to -3$},
\\
\frac{x!}{(2x)!} &\to -120\qquad\text{as $x \to -3$}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let me add to the above, that while $\Gamma(-n)$ for a positive integer $n$ is undefined, let $m$ be such an integer as well, and then the ratio $\Gamma(-n)/\Gamma(-m)$ is well defined, and the Euler reflection formula above leads to its value being equal to $\Gamma(m+1)/\Gamma(n+1)(-1)^{n-m}$.
     This shows, by the way that the ratio mentioned at the beginning of the this sequence, effectively $(-3)!/(-6)!$ is $-60$, and not as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the limit formulas
\begin{equation*}%\label{gamma-limit-eq}
\lim_{z\to-k}\frac{\Gamma(nz)}{\Gamma(qz)}=(-1)^{(n-q)k}\frac{q}{n}\frac{(qk)!}{(nk)!}, \quad k\in\{0,1,2,\dotsc\} \quad n,q\in\{1,2,\dotsc\}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation}\label{polygamma-limit-eq}
 \lim_{z\to-k}\frac{\psi(nz)}{\psi(qz)}=\frac{q}{n}, \quad k\in\{0,1,2,\dotsc\} \quad n,q\in\{1,2,\dotsc\}
\end{equation}
give a perfect answer. One can find alternative proofs of these limit formulas in the papers [1, 2, 3] below.

References

1. A. Prabhu and H. M. Srivastava, *Some limit formulas for the Gamma and Psi (or Digamma) functions at their singularities*, Integral Transforms Spec. Funct. **22** (2011), no. 8, 587--592; available online at https://doi.org/10.1080/10652469.2010.535970.
2. F. Qi, *Limit formulas for ratios between derivatives of the gamma and digamma functions at their singularities*, Filomat **27** (2013), no. 4, 601--604; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.2298/FIL1304601Q.
3. L. Yin and L.-G. Huang, *Limit formulas related to the $p$-gamma and $p$-polygamma functions at their singularities*, Filomat **29** (2015), no. 7, 1501--1505; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/FIL1507501Y.