# Gamma function of negative argument

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

Is there any relation between the limiting behaviour of $\Gamma({\epsilon})$ and $\Gamma(-1+{\epsilon})$?
I have seen the relation such as $\Gamma(-1+{\epsilon})$ $=$ $\Gamma({\epsilon})/(-1+{\epsilon})$. I think it is basically wrong? But does there exist such a similar relation?

Comment: In a small treatize on the Eulerian numbers I tried to make sense to the gamma-function at zero and negative integers including the aspect of epsilon-range deviations around the integer arguments at which the singularities occur. Perhaps this is giving some ideas to you.... see http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/01_12_Eulermatrix.pdf pg 8 ff

Comment: You may appreciate the discussion in this ['Limits defined for negative factorials'](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168223/limits-defined-for-negative-factorials-i-e-n-space-n-in-mathbbn) thread.

Answer (score 7):

The relation $\Gamma(-1+\epsilon) = \Gamma({\epsilon})/(-1+{\epsilon})$ is true so long as $\epsilon$ is not a negative integer (so that $-1+\epsilon$ will then also not be a negative integer) since the gamma function is extended to the complex plane minus the negative integers by using the relation $\Gamma(z)=\Gamma(z+1)/z$ or by using analytic continuation.

Thus, you can say something about the limiting behaviour of $\Gamma(\epsilon)$ and $\Gamma(-1+\epsilon)$, in that you can say that

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{\Gamma(-1+\epsilon)}{\Gamma(\epsilon)} = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{-1+\epsilon} = -1.$$

Note that the fact that $\Gamma(z)$ is not defined at $-1$ does not affect this, since for the limit, we are only interested in the values of the function *close to* $-1$.

In other words, $|\Gamma(z)\vert$ tends to infinity "at the same rate" as $z\to 0$ or as $z\to -1$, and similar results could be proved at any negative integer.

Comment: Well put. (+1) Computations of this sort often show up in dimensional regularization.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the limit formula
\begin{equation*}%\label{gamma-limit-eq}
\lim_{z\to-k}\frac{\Gamma(nz)}{\Gamma(qz)}=(-1)^{(n-q)k}\frac{q}{n}\frac{(qk)!}{(nk)!}, \quad k\in\{0,1,2,\dotsc\} \quad n,q\in\{1,2,\dotsc\}
\end{equation*}
is a perfect answer. One can find alternative proofs of this limit formula in the papers [1, 2, 3] below.

References

1. A. Prabhu and H. M. Srivastava, *Some limit formulas for the Gamma and Psi (or Digamma) functions at their singularities*, Integral Transforms Spec. Funct. **22** (2011), no. 8, 587--592; available online at https://doi.org/10.1080/10652469.2010.535970.
2. F. Qi, *Limit formulas for ratios between derivatives of the gamma and digamma functions at their singularities*, Filomat **27** (2013), no. 4, 601--604; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.2298/FIL1304601Q.
3. L. Yin and L.-G. Huang, *Limit formulas related to the $p$-gamma and $p$-polygamma functions at their singularities*, Filomat **29** (2015), no. 7, 1501--1505; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/FIL1507501Y.

Answer (score 0):

Your relation /would/ hold *if* $\Gamma$ were continuous at $-1$. It is not, however: intuitively, we cannot take the factorial of negative integers.

Comment: I think there are other continuations of the factorial function which are defined for negative integers. The Gamma function is a particular one which is not. I'll try and find the link to the various extensions of $n!$ that are out there.

Comment: @Peter, were you thinking of [this](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunctionMJ.html)?

Comment: @JM Yes!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding numerical computation of Gamma Function for negative real numbers, $\Gamma(x)$, can one use the relation:

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\!=\!\sum\limits^{+\infty}_{m\!=\!1}c_{m}x^{m}$$

where the only stated restriction is $\vert x\vert \leq \infty$? This formula appears in Abramowitz and Stegun (Handbook for Mathematical Functions and Tables, page 256, formula # 6.1.34