# Negative factorial over another negative factorial

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

Suppose that you wanted to take the ratio of two negative factorials, such as:
$\frac{(-n)!}{(-m)!}$ for positive integers $n,m>0$.  I am pretty sure it is well defined (binomials with a negative upper index), however I do not know how to show that through factorials.

The best shot I have at it is:
$$
\frac{(-n)!}{(-m)!}=\left (\frac{\pi n}{\sin \pi n} \right ) \frac{1}{n!} \left(\frac{\sin \pi m}{\pi m} \right ) m! = \frac{(m-1)!}{(n-1)!}\frac{\sin \pi m}{\sin \pi n}
$$
which has different answers (zero, infinity, or $\frac{(m-1)!}{(n-1)!}$ ) depending on the order of which limits are taken (with respect to $m$ or $n$).

Comment: [Somewhat relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168223/limits-defined-for-negative-factorials-i-e-n-space-n-in-mathbbn?rq=1)

Comment: What sort of values are $m,n$?  You think that limits should be taken, but without an explicit indication of those limits it is unclear how an order of the limits should be decided.

Comment: whoops, just edited to mention that they are positive integers, but to take limits you can say that they are real positive numbers that approach a positive integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factorials of negative integers can be related to the simple poles of the gamma function by:

$$ m! = \Gamma(m+1) $$

The [gamma function is meromorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), and the behavior of $\Gamma(z)$ as $z$ approaches a non-positive integer $-m+1$ is like $R/(z+m-1)$ with residue:

$$ R = \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} $$

Therefore the most natural interpretation for positive integers $n,m$ is:

$$ \frac{(-n)!}{(-m)!} = \frac{\Gamma(-n+1)}{\Gamma(-m+1)} = (-1)^{n-m}\frac{(m-1)!}{(n-1)!} $$

This is equivalent to letting complex arguments approach $-n,-m$ at equal rates.

Comment: Thanks!  That's a lot more elegant than what I concocted.